# Chat page keeps on refreshing?

Tags: bug

I am trying to access this page, but it keeps on refreshing:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311/hub-of-reason

[image]

All I see is the Loading message, and it keeps refreshing each time the loading finishes.

Browser: Google Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Any chance you have userscripts installed that cause this?

Comment: I have disabled all extensions on chrome, I still get the error.